# iOS implementing camera in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera

I'm trying to implement the camera package in flutter for android and iOS devices,
On android I don't have any problem but in iOS i get this error:
The following StateError was thrown building Builder:

```
Bad state: No element
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.first (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:332:5)
#1      _CameraState.initState (package:glass_case_flutter/controllers/camera_controller.dart:21:45)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:57)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4469:5)
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
```

this is the code of main.dart:

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<Null> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GlassCase());
}

class GlassCase extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        ResetPassword.id: (context) => ResetPassword(),
        HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(cameras),
        ProfileScreen.id: (context) => ProfileScreen()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code of my homepage.dart where I call camera.dart:

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Camera(widget.cameras)));
          },
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
```

this is my camera.dart, that is very simple, just turn on the camera:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  Camera(this.cameras);

  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        new CameraController(widget.cameras.first, ResolutionPreset.high);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return new Container();
    }
    return new AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

I added this in my Info.plist to access the camera and microphone:

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable to access your camera to capture your photo</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable to access mic to record your voice</string>
```

I don't understand why in Android it work but in iOS I get that error, somebody can help me ?
Thank so much !

Comment: Your list of cameras is empty.

Comment: You cannot access the camera in iOS simulator, you would need a physical device to test it on.

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves thanks, I didn't know it, I installed the app on a physical device and it works!